# What is the point of the titles in the Garden City of Ysa?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* several ambassadors are selling titles in Ysa, what is the point of getting one? Also, can I hold more than 1 title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you purchase a title, you can talk to the Herald, and you will be announced as such when you enter the room.

As far as I've been able to determine, it is entirely flavor.